# Why my child div get out of parent div

Tags: html, css, position

I set parent div's position be relative and child div's be absolutely. I plan to put child in the right top corner of the parent. But the child get out of its parent.
Can someone give me a reason why it happen and how to fix it.

Codes are in this link : https://jsfiddle.net/wb878L7g/

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
div#chicken {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
}
#chicken-title {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="chicken">
  <h3 id="chicken-title">chicken</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: The parent collapses as the absolutely positioned child is removed from the flow of the document. Since that parent div has no other content, it effectively shrinks to nothing. The child element *is* appearing in the top, right of the parent.

Answer (score 1):

Your div with the ID of chicken has a height that is smaller than the "chicken-title", which is why it overflows over the edge.

If you set a height to the 'div#chicken' element, the 'chicken-title' will appear how you expect it to.

For example:

```
div#chicken {
position: relative;
padding: 0;
background-color: yellow;
min-height: 200px;
}
```

Note the addition of the min-height property.

Here is a link to an edited version of your jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/wb878L7g/2/

Comment: Thanks, Josh! It works. I was wondering is there any approach I can do some settings to get a default situation that parent div has a larger height than the sum of all its children?

Comment: I believe that is how block type elements are by default if you use percentages. For example, two child divs with heights of 100% are still contained within their parent div with a height of say 200px or something. But since the chicken-title element is positioned absolutely, I think you need to explicitly declare the parent's height.